# SQL query – how to get value from array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I've been using the following SQL query to output values from my WordPress user profiles.

```
$divisions = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT Distinct(c.meta_value) 
    FROM $wpdb->usermeta AS r  
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS y
      ON r.user_id = y.user_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS g
      ON r.user_id = g.user_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS re
      ON r.user_id = re.user_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS c
      ON r.user_id = c.user_id
    WHERE r.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%'
    AND y.meta_key = 'CERTIFIED_DISPLAY'
    AND y.meta_value NOT LIKE 'no'
    AND g.meta_key = 'CERTIFIED_CATEGORY'
    AND g.meta_value = '$category'
    AND re.meta_key = 'dbem_region'
    AND re.meta_value = '$region'
    AND c.meta_key = 'dbem_school_division'
    ORDER BY c.meta_value ASC
    ");
```

It worked great until I had to change one of the meta keys ('CERTIFIED_CATEGORY') to an array. That particular field used to be a select box with a single value, and then I changed it to a checkbox list which is an array of values.  This is the part of the query I now need to fix:

```
AND g.meta_key = 'CERTIFIED_CATEGORY'
AND g.meta_value = '$category'
```

`$category` is one of the values in the array. I thought I could just change the '=' to 'LIKE', but it didn't work:

```
AND g.meta_key = 'CERTIFIED_CATEGORY'
AND g.meta_value LIKE '$category'
```

I also tried 'IN', but no luck. How can I do this?

Comment: Also: Since I switched from a single value to an array, not all users have updated their profiles – so some of the values for that key are still stored as single values. Only users who have updated their profiles recently will have an array. The above query only works for users with "single values". I need the query to work for BOTH scenarios. I thought 'LIKE' would do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all I needed to do was change this line:

```
AND g.meta_value = '$category'
```

to this:

```
AND g.meta_value LIKE '%$category%'
```

I had already tried using LIKE, but I didn't use the % signs around the variable. Apparently the % was necessary, because now it works. Wish I knew more to explain *why*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the **mysql_fetch_array** command for this.

Check the following link : [PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

In the above link there is also an example.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how to use this... do I need to re-do my entire query, or can I add this to it? I'm not well-versed in SQL queries -- I managed to patch my current query together from forums and google!